# UITextField not reading values

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var _email: MaterialField!

    @IBOutlet weak var _pass: MaterialField!

    @IBOutlet weak var _signIn: UIButton!


    @IBAction func attemptLoginWithEmail(sender : UIButton!) {

        if let email = _email.text where email != "", let password = _pass.text where password != "" {

            print(email)
        }

}
```

Program keeps crashing , the _email.text and _pass.text keep returning nil. tried for a few hours but couldn't get it to work. any help would be appreciated

Comment: If your app is crashing then you need to update your question with the full error message from the crash and point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: To learn how to debug a crash, please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: post your entire class.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply remove **weak** keyword from at the time of object preparation and now run your project its worked well.

**Note** :

A strong reference (which you will use in most cases) means that you want to "own" the object you are referencing with this property/variable. The compiler will take care that any object that you assign to this property will not be destroyed as long as you point to it with a strong reference. Only once you set the property to nil will the object get destroyed (unless one or more other objects also hold a strong reference to it).

In contrast, with a weak reference you signify that you don't want to have control over the object's lifetime. The object you are referencing weakly only lives on because at least one other object holds a strong reference to it. Once that is no longer the case, the object gets destroyed and your weak property will automatically get set to nil. The most frequent use cases of weak references in iOS are:

1.) delegate properties, which are often referenced weakly to avoid retain cycles, and

2.) subviews/controls of a view controller's main view because those views are already strongly held by the main view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what it was but I deleted func attemptLogin and made another function exactly the same referring the same button and it worked. thanks for those of you who commented